# True/False Justifications regarding Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having difficulty with true/false statements and their justifications regarding systems of linear equations.

(a) A linear system of three equations in five unknowns is always consistent (i.e. it has at least one solution)

(b) A linear system of five equations in three unknowns cannot be consistent

(c) If a linear system in echelon form is triangular then the system has the unique solution

(d) If a linear system of n equations in n unknowns has two equations that are multiples of one another,
then the system is inconsistent.

So far, for (a) I have said False, as it will always be consistent if it is homogeneous, but not if it is non-homogeneous.

For (b) I have said false, but am having difficulty justifying this assertion

(c) I know to be true.

(d) I believe may be false as having equations that are multiples could result in free variables and hence infinite solutions?

I am rather unsure on what I have done so far.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for part $b$ , you may consider below counter example :

$x_1+x_2+x_3=1$

$x_1+x_2+x_3=1$

$x_1+x_2+x_3=1$

$x_1+x_2+x_3=1$

$x_1+x_2+x_3=1$

for part $c$ , look @ 
[Is it possible for a triangular matrix in echelon form to not have a unique solution and how?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893729/is-it-possible-for-a-triangular-matrix-in-echelon-form-to-not-have-a-unique-solu)

for part $d$ :

you're correct about the answer but your reasoning is only partially correct - the system can also be inconsistent :

$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1$

$2x_1+2x_2+2x_3=2$

$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 2$

Comment: Thanks very much for that, it's greatly appreciated. How is my Part a response?

Comment: np :) your justification for part a looks perfect to me !

Comment: Could I possibly ask you to explain part C? I wasn't able to understand fully what was discussed in the link you provided

Comment: here is a triangular matrix in echelon form  $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right]$ Clearly for this system, the solutions cannot be unique as the determinant is 0. depending on the right side, it will have infinitely many or 0 solutions...

Comment: basically a triangular matrix **need not** have non zero elements in the diagonal. definition @ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UpperTriangularMatrix.html

Answer (score 0):

for part(1), I can give one example 
a+b+c+d+e=1,2a+b+c+d+e=2,3a+b+c+d+e=5, this system of three equations in 5 variables has no solution or it is inconsistent.Hence the given statement is false.
for part(2), we can have one example 
a+b+c=3, 2a+2b+c=5, 2a+b+2c=5, a+2b+2c=5, a+b+2c=4. This is a system of five equations in 3 variables with solution a=b=c=1. Hence the given statement is false.